# en javascript en date, cuales son los posibles valores de timeZone

Tags: javascript, date

estoy haciendo en JavaScript un reloj que te diga la hora en cualquier país del mundo, lo resuelvo con algo parecido a

```
const opciones = {timeZone: 'nombre_del_lugar'};
const hora = new Date().toLocaleString ('es-ES', opciones);
```

el problema es que no he conseguido encontrar donde obtener 'nombre_del_lugar' para todos los países del mundo, incluyendo las distintas zonas horarias que pueda tener cada uno, como España península y España Canarias.
Supongo que se deba a mi poca pericia con los buscadores, pero agradecería una ayuda sobre como obtener un array o una lista con dichos valores

Answer (score 0):

##### 1) Para obtener una lista de los timeszones:

```js
const timezones = Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone');
console.log(timezones);
```

##### 2) Para obtener el idioma del cliente

```js
console.log(navigator.language);
```

#### 3) Para obtener una lista de países en un idioma

(default: el del navegador)

```js
function getPaises(idioma = navigator.language) {
    const A = 65;
    const Z = 90;
    const pais = new Intl.DisplayNames([idioma], { type: 'region' });
    const paises = {};
    for(let i=A; i<=Z; ++i) {
        for(let j=A; j<=Z; ++j) {
            let code = String.fromCharCode(i) + String.fromCharCode(j);
            let name = pais.of(code);
            if(code !=name){
              paises[name.toUpperCase()] = code;
            }
            
        }
    }
    return paises;
}

console.log(getPaises());
```

##### 4) Para obtener el timezone de un país

```js
const local = new Intl.Locale("es-ES");
console.log(local.timeZones);
```

##### 5) Obtener lista de timezone según nombre del país

(Combinación de los otros códigos descritos arriba)

```js
const Paises = getPaises();
function getPaises(idioma = navigator.language) {
    const A = 65;
    const Z = 90;
    const pais = new Intl.DisplayNames([idioma], { type: 'region' });
    const paises = {};
    for(let i=A; i<=Z; ++i) {
        for(let j=A; j<=Z; ++j) {
            let code = String.fromCharCode(i) + String.fromCharCode(j);
            let name = pais.of(code);
            if(code !=name){
              paises[name.toUpperCase()] = code;
            }
            
        }
    }
    return paises;
}

function getTimeZonePorPais(pais){
  pais = pais.toUpperCase();
  const code = Intl.getCanonicalLocales(navigator.language + "-" + Paises[pais]);
  const local = new Intl.Locale(code);
  return local.timeZones;
}

console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("España"));
console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("francia")); //segundo
console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("Chile"));
console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("Estados unidos"));
console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("china"));
console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("japón"));
console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("colombia"));
console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("japón"));
console.log(getTimeZonePorPais("argentina"));
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias! lo que creía que tardaría unas semanas lo haré en unos minutos!