Como convertir fechas entre zonas horarias javascript
Estoy haciendo un programa para convertir fechas de fuso horario distinto, por ejemplo en España son las 00:07, y quiero conseguir la hora de Brasil que son las 19:07, estoy usando day.js pero no me permite hacerlo con el browser, tienen idea de como puedo hacerlo?
he usado este codigo
let utc = require("dayjs/plugin/utc");

let timezone = require("dayjs/plugin/timezone");

dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

const horaBrasil = dayjs().tz("America/Sao_Paulo");

console.log(horaBrasil);


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



Para mostrar (NO convertir) fechas en distintos timezone, sin usar librerías externas, puede utilizar toLocaleString


const date = new Date();
console.log("DateTime local: ", date.toLocaleString("es-ES"));

console.log("DateTime España: ", date.toLocaleString("es-ES",{timeZone :"Europe/Madrid"}));

console.log("DateTime Brasil: ",date.toLocaleString("es-ES",{timeZone :"America/Sao_Paulo"}));




Y para ver la lista de zonas horarias que hay, como se puede hacer?

Otra duda que tengo es en relación a los cambios de hora que se realizan en algunos países con este método toLocaleString() tiene en cuenta también esos cambios de hora?

@Pedro, ¡lee la documentación! Yussef te dejo el link a esta y allí dice dónde puedes ver la lista de las zonas horarias.

@PedroFerreira Para ver la lista de los timezone -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/610004/301324.  y si, si tiene en cuenta los cambios de horario
